# Visuals fragmented/flashed terribly

Tags: graphics, visual-artifacts

I installed Ubuntu yesterday and have got some things running on it. Today I was playing minecraft when suddenly the entire screen began to flash, I could still use the various GUIs on my system by looking between the flashes and by memory but it was otherwise completely unusable. I went into the dash and tried to shutdown but it froze and I had to do a manual reboot, which seems to have fixed the problem for now.

It seemed like the colors of random pixels were being skewed across the screen, and they formed a triangular pattern. Also, the computer had been on for hours. If anyone knows why this might have happened I'd appreciate the help.

I'm running Xenial and my graphics card is GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I was using a driver from X.org, I've seitched to the Nvidia driver now.